# How to insert a non-existing document using aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to insert an arbitrary document into an arbitrary collection using aggregation, instead of insert methods.

So far I tried:

```
db.getCollection('someCollection').aggregate([
        { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { a: 1} }},
        { $out: "outputCollection" }
    ])

db.getCollection('someCollection').aggregate([
        { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $ifNull: [ "$x", { a: 1} }},
        { $out: "outputCollection" }
    ])
```

to insert {a: 1} into collection "outputCollection". Query executes without error but there are no documents in outputCollection.

Is it possible/how to create a document without starting aggregation with some existing documents?

Comment: BTW mongo version is 3.4

Answer (score 0):

`$out` will first delete the target collection if it exists so your scheme of using multiple agg pipelines in lieu of `insert` will not work.

Starting in MongoDB 4.2 you can use the `$merge` function which has much greater flexibility.